# Conceptual framework for predicting customer probability of changing to online purchases

Tags: predictive-models, dataset, research-design

I'm likely to be tasked to create a predictive model for predicting if our customers will start using our online store. I have 2 frameworks to do it. I'm pretty certain of one framework and very unsure of the other. So I'm interested in potential problems in my solutions

1 Train and test the model with time period 1 independent variables and time period 2 dependent variable. If the model is good use model and period 2 independent variables to predict the probability of our customers becoming online store customers on a future period(3). I'm pretty confident that is good solution.

2 Train and test the model by using all past data, of course there would be also time related variables (such as x actions per last 1/3/6 months etc.) Then use the model to give probability scores for all customers that are not online customers. In this framework there would not a prediction for specific period but a more of a general evaluation on what is the potential of a customer to become an online store customer.

What are potential problems in these options? Will option 2 even work at all?